# sublime custom build command, how to?

Tags: sublimetext2

I have a program, which is using what they called `wmake` to build the code and it's very convenient. Suppose I have a folder and a C++ file: `/path/to/file.C`, all I have to do is go to `/path/to` folder and then type the `wmake` command and return and all is set.

When I am using sublimetext, I would like to open this `file.C` file and then ctrl+B to build it, but it doesn't work. Currently I customized a build system like:

```
{
    "cmd": "wmake"
}
```

the error shows as

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  wmake]
[dir:  /path/to/file.C]
[path: /home/meee/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin]
[Finished]
```

Anyone knows how to customize a build system in sublimetext2? I read the online mannual but still have no clue. Thanks

### My aim

All I want to do is to get the same effect as I type in shell window a simple

```
wmake /path/to
```

### Edit-1

I tried this, it's not working either, the same error. I dont understand why "no such file"?

```
{
    "cmd": "wmake",

    "selector" : "source.C",

    "shell": false,

    "working_dir" : "$file_path",

    "variants":

    [
        {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "wmake '${file_path}'"]
        }
    ]
}
```

### Edit-2

I tried using full path of wmake, and the error complains `environment variable $WM_OPTIONS not set`. So in shell, every time the ~/.bashrc is auto loaded, and to initialize all the environment variables, but this is not so in Sublime!!!!!!!!!!!!! What should I do???

```
{
    "cmd": "/fullpath/to/wmake",

    "selector" : "source.C",

    "shell": false,

    "working_dir" : "$file_path",

    "variants":

    [
        {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "/fullpath/to/wmake '${file_path}'"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What does `which wmake` output in your shell?

Comment: Please see this folder, https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.1.x/tree/master/wmake

Answer (score 0):

Your build command isn't complete.  See my customized C build:

```
{

  "cmd" : ["/usr/local/gfortran/bin/gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}", "-lgsl","-lgslcblas", "-lm" , "-Wall"],

  "selector" : "source.c",

  "shell":false,

  "working_dir" : "$file_path",

  "variants":

    [
       {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "/usr/local/gfortran/bin/gcc '${file}' -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm  -Wall -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
       }
    ]

}
```

Comment: try putting the full path of `wmake` in `"cmd"`

Comment: further, you need to include the current file you are working on as the one you want built.  Like ` "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "/the/full/path/wmake '${file_path}'"]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did, now the error is "wmake error: environment variable $WM_OPTIONS not set [Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]". Any ideas how to set env variables that are needed for my wmake? It seems sublime cant pass env variables. These variables were set in my ~/.bashrc

Comment: You might be able to pass env variables like this: [Sublime Forum](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2147).
`"env":{ "myvar": "myvalue"}`

Comment: As indicated in that post you mentioned, the guy can't make it either. I tried to use `env` but to no avail, this time, no error but no results and nothing happens

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25859/discussion-between-daniel-and-ags)

Comment: where did you store the custom .sublime-build file?